# Woocommerce responsive float issue

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have the following setup single product setup:

```
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span>250</span></p>

<p class="stock in-stock">6</p>

<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

.
.
.

</form>
```

For screen size under 768px I would like the result to look like this

```
[price]
[stock]
[qty + add_to_cart]
```

But it stacks like this:

```
[price]
[qty + add_to_cart] [stock]
```

This is my css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {


  .woocommerce div.product p.price {
  text-align: right;
  }

  .woocommerce div.product form.cart, 
  .woocommerce div.product p.cart {
    float: right;
  }

  .woocommerce div.product p.stock {
    float: right;
  }

}
```

How can I stack the them on top of each other?

Comment: If you want them to stack, then you shouldn't float them. `<p>` elements will `display: block` by default unless you float them.

Comment: Use `float: none`

Comment: Jeez, I see it now! I am so sorry! I need some more coffee, btw Helga I really like handball to ;)